# Error with the ereg_replace

Tags: php, phpmailer

When i place "&email&" in the message body in phpmailer the output message changes "&email&" to the e-mail address in the $to array. but it only uses the first email and it does see the rest. how do i make it get the rest emails and place it accordingly to the emails messages ?

```
$nq=0;            
for($x=0; $x<$numemails; $x++)
{
    $to = $allemails[$x];
    if ($to)
    {
        $to = ereg_replace(" ", "", $to);

        $message = ereg_replace("&email&", $to, $message);
        $subject = ereg_replace("&email&", $to, $subject);
        $qx=$x+1;

        print "Line $qx . Sending mail to $to.......";

        flush();
    }
}
```

===
i can not post below is the image link :

http://filevault.org.uk/testee/mailer_image.png

Hope you'll understand now.

Comment: Use `str_replace` or `preg_replace_all`.

Comment: **Do not use `ereg_replace()`.** First thing you should do before asking here is [read the PHP manual page](), which states not to use it any more and explains the alternatives. PHP 5.3 will issue a warning you if you use it and PHP 5.4 removes the function completely. So if you're still using it at all, it probably means you're also using PHP 5.2 or earlier, which is also badly out-dated. You should seriously consider upgrading to at least 5.3, for many reasons, but mostly because 5.2 hasn't had any security updates in two and a half years, and has known security holes.

Comment: Till now no person here can help me on this or understand what am talking about....hmmmmm

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be using `ereg_*` anymore as it is deprecated - [`preg_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is it's successor, though it looks like you only need [`str_replace`](https://www.php.net/str_replace) anyway:

```
$message = str_replace("&email&",$to,$message);
```

If for some reason you really have to use ereg:

You may need the global flag `g`

```
ereg_replace("&email&g",
```

**Different replacement every time**

```
$to = array('email1@me.com','em2@me.com');
$text = 'asdkfjalsdkf &email& and then &email&';
$email_replacements = $to;
function replace_emails()
{
    global $email_replacements;
    return array_shift($email_replacements); //removes the first element of the array of emails, and then returns it as the replacement
}
var_dump(preg_replace_callback('#&email&#','replace_emails',$text));
//"asdkfjalsdkf email1@me.com and then em2@me.com"
```

Integrated:

```
$to = $allemails[$x];
$email_replacements = $to;
function replace_emails()
{
    global $email_replacements;
    return array_shift($email_replacements); //removes the first element of the array of emails, and then returns it as the replacement
}

if($to)
{
    $message = preg_replace_callback('#&email&#','replace_emails',$message);

    $subject = preg_replace_callback('#&email&#','replace_emails',$subject);
    $qx=$x+1;
    print "Line $qx . Sending mail to $to.......";

    flush();
```

Comment: how do i post an image so u understand ? cos everything is working fine just that it only passes the first email address to both email i test it with and the other one. how do i make it get the email one at a time for each email address ...."one &email& for one email address"

Comment: see the image so you can understand what am talking about more http://filevault.org.uk/testee/mailer_image.png

Comment: Where do i put the codes exactly cos am realy new to php ?

Comment: can send you a link of the code so u can try it on your side ?

Comment: that is the full phpmailer code http://speedy.sh/mHv7N/o2jscript.zip

Comment: @user2672616 `preg_replace_callback` is being used instead of `ereg_replace` - see updated answer for an integrated solution

Comment: I tried the codes you wrote but it only sends the first email and liv the other one , also when i used the #&email&# it only apeared as ##, please Line 2864 ru 2879 of the original php codes that is where i think the problem is.. Thanks

Comment: @user2672616 Can you add to your question what exactly you're trying to achieve? Are you sending one email with lots of `&email&` replacements in it, or sending multiple emails with each one having multiple `&email&` replacements (or send multiple emails with only one `&email&` replacement per email)

Comment: I am sending one email with lots of &email& replacements in it,. so you have beta idea of what am talking about you can check the mailer image here: http://filevault.org.uk/testee/mailer_image.png ,it's one message body but mutiple email addresses. what am trying to achieve is for the &email& to replace one email at a time, like the image shows, in the yahoo inbox you can see the yahoo email ID but the hotmail inbox is also showing the yahoo email ID instead of showing the Hotmail email ID as it is in the second line of the email text area of the phpmailer.

Comment: This is the full PHPmailer codes : http://speedy.sh/mHv7N/o2jscript.zip

Comment: @user2672616 Your closing `}` for your `for` loop ends too late, move the bracket from line `2927` to `2879` (just above `new PHPMailer()`)

Comment: thanks but it still do the same thing , only the first email on the list is shown in both mails when i put &email& in my message body

Comment: Till now no person here can help me on this or understand what am talking about....hmmmmm